# Magento 2 delete one month old files or images

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7, php-7.2

The below code will delete **pub/media/tmp**  directory and sub directory all files which is older than one month.By the help of core php function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    /**
     * NOTICE OF LICENSE
     *
     * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
     * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
     * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
     * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
     *
     * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2022 MageVikas, Inc.
     * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
     */
    
    namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Cron;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    
    class RemoveTmpDir
    {
    
        /**
         * @var LoggerInterface
         */
        protected $logger;
    
        /**
         * @var Filesystem
         */
        protected $fileSystem;
    
        /**
         * @param LoggerInterface $logger
         * @param Filesystem $fileSystem
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
         */
        public function __construct(
            LoggerInterface $logger,
            Filesystem      $fileSystem
        ) {
            $this->logger       = $logger;
            $this->directory    = $fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $this->filesystem   = $fileSystem;
        }
    
        /**
         * Remove tmp dir from pub/media
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $this->logger->info('Start Execution of tmp delete cron');
            try {
                $this->deleteFiles();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->info('Execute tmp delete cron Exception');
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
            $this->logger->info('End Execution of tmp delete cron');
        }
    
        /**
         * Delete folder and sub folder files
         *
         * @param  string $mediaPath
         * @param  string $interval
         * @return int
         * @throws LocalizedException
         */
        public function deleteFiles($mediaPath = null, $interval = null)
        {
            $deletedFiles = 0;
            $absolutePath = $this->directory->getAbsolutePath();
            $mediaTmpPath = ($mediaPath) ? $absolutePath . $mediaPath : $absolutePath . DirectoryList::TMP;
            $interval     = ($interval) ? strtotime($interval) : strtotime('-1 month');//files older than 1 month
            try {
                foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($mediaTmpPath, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME),
                    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
                ) as $info) {
                    if ($info->isFile() && $info->isReadable()) {
                        if (filemtime($info->getPathname()) <= $interval) {// phpcs:ignore
                            if ($this->directory->delete($info->getPathname())) {
                                $deletedFiles++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->info('Tmp file deletion error');
            }
            $this->logger->info('Deleted Tmp Files : ' . $deletedFiles);
            return $deletedFiles;
        }
    }
```