# Is it safe to delete images under pub/media/tmp/catalog/product

Tags: magento2.4.3

I am very much new to magento and seeing issue with server space in magento ver 2.4.3. After checking on server find out my most of the space on server occupied by **public_html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product** folder and it has images.

We are hosting our product images on aws s3 bucket and every product catalog images are synced and exist there. So here comes my questions-

1- Is it safe to remove everything from **public_html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product** folder

2- What is the use of the **public_html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product** folder images

3- Is there any way we can delete/remove images from **public_html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product** folder on regular basis or no images being copied there at all.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. It's safe
2. When admin user upload any image in Product edit form - they physically upload to server in `tmp` directory and copy into `catalog/product` on save
3. You can configure some crontab and remove with command line or try to use [Magento 2 delete one month old files or images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356338/magento-2-delete-one-month-old-files-or-images) (i've not tested)

   Example of command to remove files older 1 day

   ```
   find /path/to/tmp -mtime +1 -delete
   ```